# WordPress static homepage doesn't load

Tags: wordpress, elementor

the home page was created on elementor and it saved public as home page but when i select it on settings -> reading -> static -> home page , it doesn't load I only get the header instead of the full content  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maUpm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it , its seems like the plugins were the problem when I deactivate all of them and then activate only the once I need fixed the problem